# Starting/Stopping .NET Core app under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, sh

I have an app created in `.NET Core` and I want to run it under Ubuntu, so to run it this is what I do:

```
sudo dotnet App.dll &
```

and to stop it I have to remember the process id and then run:

```
sudo -kill kill <procId>
```

The questions:

- How should the `.sh` file look like to run/stop the service?
- I mentioned "remember the process Id" because when I run the service and then run `ps -a` then I can see the process Id, but if I log off and run this command later then it does not show me the `procId`. Why is that? I also tried some other commands to show the running procs but with those commands/utils I was unable to distinguish my process.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you would like to auto-start your dotnet application after reboot in Ubuntu, you can reference [UpstartHowto - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto) to write your own initscript.
2. When you run your application in the background, you can keep the proccess Id in the `$!` variable immediately. Please check the screenshot below:

   [image]

   After you log off and login again.  If you want to kill your process, you can try this: `` kill `cat mymvc.pid` ``